# Handle large list of images with RecyclerView and Picasso issues

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable, picasso

**Update**
I identified my problem.  I am trying to handle the large list of images (770 images in the .webp format total size of images is 10mb) with RecyclerView and it is showing out of memory error. 
How to solve this problem?     
I am using  picasso for loading images

Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 810076 byte allocation with 107504 free bytes and 104KB until OOM"

**Old**
**There is no problem if the list size is less than 100, How to load 700 item using recycler view . Each item contains image in webp formant**
I am trying this code and it is throwing out of memory error and crash the app . How to solve this error?
(It contain 700 iamges and all in webp format and this code inside recyclerview with grid layout)

```
 InputStream ins = null;

                try {
                    ins = mContext.getAssets().open(mData.get(position).getImagename()+".webp");
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ins);
                    holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (ins != null)
                        try {
                            ins.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) { }
                }
```

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
>                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
>                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:805)
>                                                          at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:845)
>                                                          at tropicalfishhandbook.midhilaj.com.v2.a.a.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at tropicalfishhandbook.midhilaj.com.v2.a.a.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
>                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:1235)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                          at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:327)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.h.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.a(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(Unknown Source)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:696)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:589)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16749)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5295)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1413)
>                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(Lin

my manifest file

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

**Update**
I replaced with Picasso and it is working in the smartphone with 2gb ram and it is crashing in the smartphone with 500mb and it also crash sometime in 1gb ram smartphone 

after adding picasso now images take 5sec to load

**updated new code**
 *but problem not solved*

This is the code I am using to load

```
try {
                       List<Millafish_profile> list = mDatabaseManager.getAll();
                       for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                           final int finalI = i;//"@drawable/" +
                           String uri = list.get(i).getPic().replace("’", "_").replace(".jpg", "").replace(".png", "").replace("-", "_");  // where myresource (without the extension) is the file
                           // Log.i("uri_"+i,uri+"");
                           Millafish_profile millafish_profile = list.get(i);//mDatabaseManager.getprofile(mDatabaseManager.getallfishname().get(finalI));
                           millafish_profile.setImageuri(uri.toLowerCase());
                           millafish_profileList.add(millafish_profile);
                           //if(i==20)break;

                           {
                               //adapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
                               //(millafish_profileList.size());
                           }

                       }
                       adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                       millafish_profileList_org = new ArrayList<>();
                       millafish_profileList_org.addAll(millafish_profileList);

                   }catch (Exception e){
                       Log.e("homepage",e.getMessage()+"");
                   }
```

Comment: did u tried to compress bitmap

Comment: no, I don't try to compress

Comment: the code is shared with question

Comment: so tried to compress see my ans

Comment: Definitely it will crash and will have memory issue as images are too much. Better to use ListView or RecyclerView to load images one by one. By using this only rendered images will load in memory instead of all the images at once.

Comment: I am checking please wait

Comment: i tryed with 10 images and it is still crashing in small mobiles and no problem in large mobiles(large menas 2gb ram)

Comment: add after holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);   if (! bitmap.isRecycled()) {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }

Comment: Try to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) this libraries handle loading images with Recycling.

Comment: how to load image from assets folder using picasso ?

Comment: Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834833/1283715),

Comment: You are trying to load in all images in one go. That is not how it is supposed to work. The chance is there that if you wrote a desktop app and trying to achieve the same with those 700 images, some cheap laptop systems will crash. Either load one by one or use `ListView` or `RecyclerView`.

Comment: @KarelG OP mentioned that `code inside recyclerview or ....`

Comment: Check `RecyclerView` [guide to learn how to implement `Recycler adapter`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java) with the right way.

Answer (score 0):

**Add dependency**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

**[RESOURCE LOADING](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.get().load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.get().load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

**In your case**

```
final String imagePath = "file:///android_asset/" + mData.get(position).getImagename()+".webp";

Picasso.get().load(imagePath).into(holder.image);
```

**Update**

```
Picasso.get()
.load(imagePath)
.centerCrop()
.fit()
// .resize(100, 100)  // Check if resize can help without fit/centerCrop
.memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE)
.into(holder.image);
```

**Update 2**

**[Implement RecyclerView adapter.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java)**

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {
      private final List<Millafish_profile> dataSet;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            image = v.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        }
    }

  public MyAdapter(){
    this.dataSet = mDatabaseManager.getAll();
  }
  // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View myView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_view_that_contains_imageview, parent, false);
        ...
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(myView);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        final String imagePath = "file:///android_asset/" + dataSet.get(position).getImagename()+".webp";
        Picasso.get().load(imagePath).into(holder.image);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataSet.size();
    }
```

- `RecyclerView` will handle load more images with user scrolling.

**`onBindViewHolder`** is called when need to displayed items on the screen then your display logic will be there and Just load on item based to position.

Comment: I replaced with picasso and it is working in mobile phone with 2gb ram and not working in mobile with 500mb and crash some time in 1gb ram smart phone

Comment: Check `Picasso fit() or resize` methods.

Comment: it it like this                             Picasso.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+mData.get(position).getImagename()+".webp")).fit().into(holder.image);

Comment: Check this [Github issue](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/305),

Comment: Check `skipMemoryCache()`, BTW latest versions is using `Picasso.get()` not `Picasso.with(mContext)`

Comment: updated and still error and what is and where is to add skipMemoryCache()?

Comment: Picasso.get().load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+mData.get(position).getImageuri()+".webp")) .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE).fit().into(holder.image);
but if i load 700 images it crash

Comment: Why do you need to load 700 image at the same time, You already use `RecyclerView` that mean recyclering of image loading and only load displayed image then with scroll load another.

Comment: How to do that ?

Comment: If display many images on the screen, This mean you must use `Picasso.get()
.load(imagePath)
.resize(width, 0)  // 0 for height equal width or you can explicitly provide height.
.into(imagePath);`

Comment: I don't need to load 700 images at a time

Comment: Will check you question update, and update my answer ASAP,

Comment: Check **Update 2** to check to implement RecyclerView adapter on the right way, Don't forget to check document link added on the update.

Comment: what do you mean by this <br>public ImageView image;
        public ViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            image = v;
        }  imageview is not a textview

Answer (score 0):

Remove Picasso and use Glide

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/"+mData.get(position).getImageuri()+".webp"))
                                .thumbnail(0.5f)

                                .into(holder.image);
```